# Categorize data in given group labels

Tags: python, pandas

Hi guys this question has been answered multiple times here , I did like to just get assistance on what I am doing wrong. I have a large dataset and I did like to categorize one column that has weights in kilograms into given labels.  Here is how my dataset looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = { 'birth_wt': [0.1, 3, 2.4, 3, 4.2, 1.3, 1.45, 0.45, 1.64, 3.011, 3.45, 1.4]}


datt = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['birth_wt'])
```

Here is my code of what I tried that isnt working

```
#Categorize birth weight 
pd.cut(datt['birth_wt'], bins=[1,1.5,2.5,4], include_lowest=True,labels=['1kg and below','1kg-1.5kg', '1.5kg-2.5','2.5kg-3.9kg', '4kg and above'])
```

This line of code is not working, any help will be appreciated, I have to categorize in given labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the lower bound and upper bound in your bins. One quick way would be to use `-inf` and `inf` as the lower and upper bound:

```
import math
pd.cut(datt['birth_wt'], bins=[-math.inf, 1,1.5,2.5,4, math.inf], include_lowest=True,labels=['1kg and below','1kg-1.5kg', '1.5kg-2.5','2.5kg-3.9kg', '4kg and above'])

0     1kg and below
1       2.5kg-3.9kg
2         1.5kg-2.5
3       2.5kg-3.9kg
4     4kg and above
5         1kg-1.5kg
6         1kg-1.5kg
7     1kg and below
8         1.5kg-2.5
9       2.5kg-3.9kg
10      2.5kg-3.9kg
11        1kg-1.5kg
Name: birth_wt, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [1kg and below < 1kg-1.5kg < 1.5kg-2.5 < 2.5kg-3.9kg < 4kg and above]
```

Comment: Is it possible I have a separate column with this categories

Comment: @LivingstoneM You can assign it as a column: datt['category'] = pd.cut(...)

Comment: Thank you very much